# Show specific div based on multiple checked radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show a certain div based on a number of radio button selections.  So, I would like it to show div9 if div0=symptomatic, div1=negative, & div2=normal, however I am not getting that result. Thank you!

```js
function show1(){
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display ='block';
 }
function show2(){
   document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
 }
function show3(){
   document.getElementById('div2').style.display ='block';
 }
function show4(){
   document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
 }
function show5(){
 if ('input[value=div0symp]:checked, input[value=div1neg]:checked, input[value=div2norm]:checked').length == 3)
  document.getElementById('div9').style.display = 'block';
    }
```

```html
<div id="div0" class="show">
  <input type="radio" name="tab" id='div0symp' value="symptomatic" onclick="show1();" /> Patient is symptomatic
  <input type="radio" name="tab" id='div0asymp' value="asymptomatic" onclick="show2();" /> Patient is asymptomatic
</div>

<div id="div1" class="hide">
  <hr>
  <p>Test the patient<br> Test Result is:</p>
  <input type="radio" id='div1pos' name="tab2" value="positive" onclick="show3()"> Positive &nbsp;
  <input type="radio" id='div1neg' name="tab2" value="negative" onclick="show4()"> Negative
</div>

<div id="div2" class="hide">
  <hr>
  <p>Perform an X-Ray </p>
  <input type="radio" id='div2norm' name="tab3" value="normal" onclick="show5()"> Normal &nbsp;
  <input type="radio" id='div2abn' name="tab3" value="abnormal" onclick="show6()"> Abnormal
</div>

<div id="div9" class="hide">
  <hr>
  <p>No further evaluation unless<br>
    <strong>contact</strong> or <strong>immunosupressed/HIV</strong></p>
  <input type="submit" name="tab7" value="nextstep" onclick="show10()"> &nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: you are missing a `$(` in your `show5()` function.

Comment: Also you're missing `show6()` and `show10()` functions.

Comment: I didn't include the show6() and show10() in the code above.  Those don't appear to be an issue, it's just this show5() that is not running correctly.

Comment: your if statement in show5 needs to be `if ($('input[value=div0symp]:checked, input[value=div1neg]:checked, input[value=div2norm]:checked').length == 3)`

Comment: `show1()` and `show2()` could be `showX()` and `show3()`  and `show4()` could be `showY()`

Comment: @IrkenInvader why jQuery? Nobody talks jQuery here

Comment: dunno, looked like a jquery selector, is it a queryselector?

Comment: I'm very new with this, so if there's a better way than what I have above, I greatly appreciate the advice!

Comment: @IrkenInvader thank you! I modified as you suggested, but the div9 isn't displaying on clicking the normal x-ray radio button. Is the display segment incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the main important difference will be found in the `if()` statement.

Note:

1. I've disabled some input fields as they are not really relevant to the question as you need to click on the not disabled ones to see whats going on.
2. See the function name changes from `show1()` to `showX()` it's bad naming. But if a function does the same thing as another one there is no reason to do a `show2()` doing the same as `show1()`..

```js
function showX(){
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display ='block';
 }
function showY(){
   document.getElementById('div2').style.display ='block';
 }
function show5(){
    if(
        document.getElementById('div0symp').checked
        && document.getElementById('div1neg').checked
        && document.getElementById('div2norm').checked
    ) {
        document.getElementById('div9').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="div0" class="show">
  <input type="radio" name="tab" id='div0symp' value="symptomatic" onclick="showX();" /> Patient is symptomatic
  <input disabled type="radio" name="tab" id='div0asymp' value="asymptomatic" onclick="showX();" /> Patient is asymptomatic
</div>

<div id="div1" class="hide">
  <hr>
  <p>Test the patient<br> Test Result is:</p>
  <input disabled type="radio" id='div1pos' name="tab2" value="positive" onclick="showY()"> Positive &nbsp;
  <input type="radio" id='div1neg' name="tab2" value="negative" onclick="showY()"> Negative
</div>

<div id="div2" class="hide">
  <hr>
  <p>Perform an X-Ray </p>
  <input type="radio" id='div2norm' name="tab3" value="normal" onclick="show5()"> Normal &nbsp;
  <input disabled type="radio" id='div2abn' name="tab3" value="abnormal" onclick="show6()"> Abnormal
</div>

<div id="div9" class="hide">
  <hr>
  <p>No further evaluation unless<br>
    <strong>contact</strong> or <strong>immunosupressed/HIV</strong></p>
  <input type="submit" name="tab7" value="nextstep" onclick="show10()"> &nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: this is much better. Thank you for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely a much better answer that the one you originally selected. However, I wouldn't use `querySelector` when using IDs, and I wouldn't specify the element `input` with IDs either. Just go with simple `getElementById` like you did everywhere else. See the last solution in my answer.

Comment: @RacilHilan why you say "I wouldn't use querySelector when using IDs"? There is pretty much no difference in using one over the other. Especially not in this case.

Comment: Because IDs must be unique in HTML, and selecting by IDs is the most efficient (=fastest) in JavaScript. Going through the element `input` and then the ID doesn't make any sense. Even reading it is soar to the eye. Heck, even if they are identical (they are not), why do we type `input#` three times to get the same thing? `getElementById` is cleaner, clearer and easier to read & write.

Comment: @RacilHilan thanks for feedback. updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using jQuery, so you can fix `show5()` like this:

```js
function show1() {
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
}

function show2() {
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
}

function show3() {
  document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
}

function show4() {
  document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
}

function show5() {
  if ($('input[id=div0symp]:checked, input[id=div1neg]:checked, input[id=div2norm]:checked').length == 3)
    document.getElementById('div9').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div0" class="show">
  <input type="radio" name="tab" id='div0symp' value="symptomatic" onclick="show1();" /> Patient is symptomatic
  <input type="radio" name="tab" id='div0asymp' value="asymptomatic" onclick="show2();" /> Patient is asymptomatic
</div>

<div id="div1" class="hide">
  <hr>
  <p>Test the patient<br> Test Result is:</p>
  <input type="radio" id='div1pos' name="tab2" value="positive" onclick="show3()"> Positive &nbsp;
  <input type="radio" id='div1neg' name="tab2" value="negative" onclick="show4()"> Negative
</div>

<div id="div2" class="hide">
  <hr>
  <p>Perform an X-Ray </p>
  <input type="radio" id='div2norm' name="tab3" value="normal" onclick="show5()"> Normal &nbsp;
  <input type="radio" id='div2abn' name="tab3" value="abnormal" onclick="show6()"> Abnormal
</div>

<div id="div9" class="hide">
  <hr>
  <p>No further evaluation unless<br>
    <strong>contact</strong> or <strong>immunosupressed/HIV</strong></p>
  <input type="submit" name="tab7" value="nextstep" onclick="show10()"> &nbsp;
</div>
```

However, it is better not to use attribute selectors, just go straight like this:

```js
function show1() {
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
}

function show2() {
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
}

function show3() {
  document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
}

function show4() {
  document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
}

function show5() {
  if ($('#div0symp:checked, #div1neg:checked, #div2norm:checked').length == 3)
    document.getElementById('div9').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div0" class="show">
  <input type="radio" name="tab" id='div0symp' value="symptomatic" onclick="show1();" /> Patient is symptomatic
  <input type="radio" name="tab" id='div0asymp' value="asymptomatic" onclick="show2();" /> Patient is asymptomatic
</div>

<div id="div1" class="hide">
  <hr>
  <p>Test the patient<br> Test Result is:</p>
  <input type="radio" id='div1pos' name="tab2" value="positive" onclick="show3()"> Positive &nbsp;
  <input type="radio" id='div1neg' name="tab2" value="negative" onclick="show4()"> Negative
</div>

<div id="div2" class="hide">
  <hr>
  <p>Perform an X-Ray </p>
  <input type="radio" id='div2norm' name="tab3" value="normal" onclick="show5()"> Normal &nbsp;
  <input type="radio" id='div2abn' name="tab3" value="abnormal" onclick="show6()"> Abnormal
</div>

<div id="div9" class="hide">
  <hr>
  <p>No further evaluation unless<br>
    <strong>contact</strong> or <strong>immunosupressed/HIV</strong></p>
  <input type="submit" name="tab7" value="nextstep" onclick="show10()"> &nbsp;
</div>
```

And in that case, you don't need jQuery, you can use simple JavaScript:

```js
function show1() {
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
}

function show2() {
  document.getElementById('div1').style.display = 'block';
}

function show3() {
  document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
}

function show4() {
  document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
}

function show5() {
  if (document.getElementById('div0symp').checked
   && document.getElementById('div1neg').checked
   && document.getElementById('div2norm').checked)
      document.getElementById('div9').style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="div0" class="show">
  <input type="radio" name="tab" id='div0symp' value="symptomatic" onclick="show1();" /> Patient is symptomatic
  <input type="radio" name="tab" id='div0asymp' value="asymptomatic" onclick="show2();" /> Patient is asymptomatic
</div>

<div id="div1" class="hide">
  <hr>
  <p>Test the patient<br> Test Result is:</p>
  <input type="radio" id='div1pos' name="tab2" value="positive" onclick="show3()"> Positive &nbsp;
  <input type="radio" id='div1neg' name="tab2" value="negative" onclick="show4()"> Negative
</div>

<div id="div2" class="hide">
  <hr>
  <p>Perform an X-Ray </p>
  <input type="radio" id='div2norm' name="tab3" value="normal" onclick="show5()"> Normal &nbsp;
  <input type="radio" id='div2abn' name="tab3" value="abnormal" onclick="show6()"> Abnormal
</div>

<div id="div9" class="hide">
  <hr>
  <p>No further evaluation unless<br>
    <strong>contact</strong> or <strong>immunosupressed/HIV</strong></p>
  <input type="submit" name="tab7" value="nextstep" onclick="show10()"> &nbsp;
</div>
```

Comment: Why jQuery? jQuery is not tagged to this question!

Comment: Like I said at the beginning, the way she has it in the question looks like a jQuery selector. Of course it can be done without jQuery, which is why I added the last solution.